# ReactJS: update child's state from parent function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, draggable

I am checking the position of all draggables against the one I am dragging to detect if collision occurs.

If yes, I want to update the position of the draggable that I am dragging (something like forcing it to snap to some place, or force it not overlapping with others).

How can I update the child's state (`currentPosition`) in a parent function?

```js
function Parent() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    function checkPosition(item) {
        items.forEach((i) => {
            if (item.position hasCollisionWith i.position) {
                // how can I achieve something like this?
                item.setCurrentPosition(new_position);
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {items.map((i) => <Child item={i} checkPosition={checkPosition} />)}
        </div>
    );
}

function Child({item, checkPosition}) {
    const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(item.position);

    function handleDrag(event, dragElement) {
        // update position of item during dragging
        setCurrentPosition({x: dragElement.x, y: dragElement.y});
        item.position = currentPosition;

        // check position of this item against other items
        checkPosition(item);
    }

    return (
        <Draggable position={currentPosition} onDrag={handleDrag}>
            some_content_here
        </Draggable>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move logic to parent and pass onDrag handler as callback:

```
type Item = {
    id: number
    position: { x: number; y: number }
}

function Parent() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([])

    const itemHasCollision = (_item: Item, _position: { x: number; y: number }): boolean => {
        // todo: check if item has collision with other items
        return false
    }

    const handleDrag = (item: Item, newPosition: { x: number; y: number }) => {
        if (itemHasCollision(item, newPosition)) {
            const updatedItems = items.map((i) => {
                if (i.id === item.id) {
                    // for example snap to default place
                    i.position = { x: 0, y: 0 }
                }

                return i
            })

            setItems(updatedItems)
        } else {
            const updatedItems = items.map((i) => {
                if (i.id === item.id) {
                    i.position = newPosition
                }

                return i
            })

            setItems(updatedItems)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {items.map((i) => (
                <Child key={i.id} item={i} onDrag={handleDrag} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

type ChildProps = {
    item: Item
    onDrag: (item: Item, newPosition: { x: number; y: number }) => void
}

function Child({ item, onDrag }: ChildProps) {
    const handleDrag = (event: any, dragElement: any) => {
        onDrag(item, { x: dragElement.x, y: dragElement.y })
    }

    return (
        <Draggable position={item.position} onDrag={handleDrag}>
            some_content_here
        </Draggable>
    )
}
```